# Attack on stream cipher

Tags: stream-cipher, lfsr

I am trying to decrypt a message, which was encrypted using a stream cipher and 8 bit LFSR.

First two letters of plain text are given: `K` and `A`.

To find $X_n$ I used following formula:

$$X_n = M_n \oplus Y_n$$

I found $X_1 = 81$ and $X_2 = 65$.

Assuming the next step would be to find $C_1,C_2,\dots,C_n$ then how can I find them?

Comment: Could you say what the $X_i$, $C_i$, $M_i$ and $Y_i$'s represent here? That would probably make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: M - plain text, Y - encrypted text

Comment: If $Y_n$ is the ciphertext, then what is $C_n$? If it’s also ciphertext, you might want to edit your question and settle for using $C_n$ everywhere as that will avoid confusion. At first, I expected $Y_n$ to be the key and $X_n$ the ciphertext – which is obviously wrong when looking at your comment.

Comment: seems like a homework - so - what have you tried , what are you block with? If we see some effort, you will provide you a hint as well :) are you assuming that the  `8 bit LFSR` is the stream cipher?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming as you specified that $X_1$ is $81$ and $X_2$ is $65$.
$X_1 || \ldots || X_n$ is your key stream **in bits**.

So you need to convert 81 and 65 into bits.

- $81 = \texttt{01010001}$
- $65 = \texttt{01100101}$

Thus your key stream is : $\texttt{01010001 01100101}$

You are attacking a 8 bit LFSR and we will assume Galois mode (because it is easier in this case).

The diagram of such LFSR is:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|             |           |           |           |            |           |           |            |
|            *a          *b          *c          *d           *e          *f          *g            |
|             |           |           |           |            |           |           |            |
|    +-----+  |  +-----+  |  +-----+  |  +-----+  |  +-----+   |  +-----+  |  +-----+  |  +-----+   |
|    |     |  |  |     |  |  |     |  |  |     |  |  |     |   |  |     |  |  |     |  |  |     |   |
+--->+  x0 +---->|  x1 +---->|  x2 +---->|  x3 +---->|  x4 +----->   x5 +---->|  x6 +---->|  x7 +-------> ...
     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |     |     |     |     |     |
     +-----+     +-----+     +-----+     +-----+     +-----+      +-----+     +-----+     +-----+
```

where `a` `b` `c` `d` `e` `f` `g` are constants set to `0` or `1` to determine whether a bit influence the next result.

You must notice that the output is actually decided 8 rounds before being seen.

Thus you can see the LFSR as following parallel formulas:

$out \leftarrow x_7$
$x_7 \leftarrow x_6$
$x_6 \leftarrow x_5$
$x_5 \leftarrow x_4$
$x_4 \leftarrow x_3$
$x_3 \leftarrow x_2$
$x_2 \leftarrow x_1$
$x_1 \leftarrow x_0$
$x_0 \leftarrow f(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7)$

where 
$$f(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7) = \\
(x_0 \land a) \oplus
(x_1 \land b) \oplus
(x_2 \land c) \oplus
(x_3 \land d) \oplus
(x_4 \land e) \oplus
(x_5 \land f) \oplus
(x_6 \land g) \oplus x_7$$

From this you can deduce:

$f(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0) = 0$ and the LFSR returned $0$
$f(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1) = 1$ and the LFSR returned $1$
$f(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0) = 1$ and the LFSR returned $0$
$\ldots$
and finally:
$f(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1) = 1$ and the LFSR returned $1$

Notice that the first column is the second part of the stream : $\texttt{011}\ldots \texttt{1}$ and the second column (*LFSR returned*) is your first part of the stream: $\texttt{010}\ldots \texttt{1}$

*Intermediates steps not provided as it is your homework.*

Thus this gives you 8 equations to solve with 7 variables ($a,b,c,d,e,f,g$).

*Equations not provided (nor solved) as it is your homework.*

From this you have will have recovered the complete state and will know the formula to compute the next outputs bit, giving you full prediction on the stream to attack $C_1, \ldots, C_n$.